# How to guarantee that a Windows domain user has logged in to a machine before?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

I need to place an executable in a given user's Startup folder. If Windows is connected to a domain, it won't create a user folder until they log in. If I create the Startup folder manually, Windows doesn't use it and creates another one named .domain instead. I need a way to log in a user (with Powershell, batch, or .NET) or create this folder in a way that Windows will use it. Powershell's Enter-PSSession cmdlet isn't suitable because it requires configuration on the other end.

This program needs to be run remotely using the built-in Win32 API function LogonUser. We already have this functionality in place for installing other software remotely. I just need a way to guarantee that the Startup folder exists or to create it myself.

Is there a way to do this without actually logging in as that user manually?

Comment: Are you using group policy?

Comment: Theoretically you can log in programmatically via Remote Desktop, but it is very difficult and I don't know whether anybody has ever successfully implemented this.  In some contexts, you can use the AutoAdminLogin feature to programmatically log in interactively; the main complication is that you have to reboot.  In your scenario, it would be much easier to put the executable in the global startup folder instead.

Comment: Alternatively to @HarryJohnston idea, you could also just put it in the Default profile on every computer, or use group policy to push it down. Both are more standardized and do not require you to pass user credentials around which isn't good juju

Comment: You could also look into Active Setup if you need to simply ensure an application is installed. I have never found any official MS documentation on it though.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aruns_blog/archive/2011/06/20/active-setup-registry-key-what-it-is-and-how-to-create-in-the-package-using-admin-studio-install-shield.aspx

Comment: We had a similar problem once and solved it by using the machine startup folder instead. We then had logic inside the program (or a wrapper script) to check if the user was the correct one. You can even set the acls so that the right user can delete it after he ran it

Comment: Thanks everyone. The global Startup folder looks like it will solve this problem nicely.